# Google Swiffy multiple movies on one page

Tags: google-swiffy

I'm trying to create multiple swiffy.Stage() movies on one page.
But it seems that when there are multiple Flash movies on a page, only one of the movies will actually run as it should.  I have to call their stage.tick functions manually.

EDIT:  With multiple sound containing flash, only one will play correctly.

EDIT:
The expected behavior is that "tick()" is handled by the Swiffy runtime after running "start()".  Unfortunately it seems that the Swiffy runtime will only handle the tick function for one movie per page.

Comment: You have to call their `stage.tick` functions manually, and your question is...?

Comment: That is not the expected behavior.  Calling .start() should start the "tick loop" that should automatically call stage.tick().  This way I will have to recreate my own tick loop for all swiffy movies on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was not multiple movies, but that some of the movies were not on the screen or invisible, and so were not being rendered by Chrome.  It seems that Chrome optimizes away draws that aren't visible.